# Getting Place ID based on Place Name, City Name and Address from Google Places API service

Tags: api, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places API service(https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/) to get the place id based on location name. The user types some location name and related suggestions appear from which the user can select and get the place Id. I have a requirement where I need to have three textboxes and a button. The user will enter Place Name, City Name and Address and click the button to get placeId. Right now, I don't see an option to get place Id based on more than one parameter. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5):

[Text Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) accept a query string.  One potential solution would be to allow your users to enter the place name, city, and address into different text fields, but then concatenate all of them into a single query string before sending your ajax request.

Your form looks something like this:

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="place" value="">
  <input type="text" name="city" value="">
  <input type="text" name="address" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Locate">
</form>
```

Your javascript will look something like this:

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {

  // concatenate places into a single query string
  var query = $('input[name="place"]').val() + $('input[name="city"]').val() + $('input[name="address"]').val();

  // convert spaces to '+' symbol for query
  query = encodeURIComponent(query);

  // send ajax request
  $.ajax({url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=" + query + "&key=YOUR_API_KEY", success: function(result){
        alert('success, now retrieve your id from result variable');
    }});

  //prevent the submit button from reloading the page
  event.preventDefault();
});
```